# Programatically go to next compilation error

Tags: compilation-mode

When I am refactoring code, I often need to make the same change in my files.  My current workflow is often something like this:

- `M-x grep` for `foo.bar.baz`
- Go to first hit
- `M-x replace-string RET foo.bar RET foo`
- Go to next hit
- Repeat previous two lines until no more hits

Keyboard macros and `M-p` can help with this, but I tried to write a function to do all the replacements in a simple command: `M-x my-replace-grep-hits RET foo.bar RET foo`.

I am having trouble figuring out how to actually get to the file with the error.  It seems that

```
      (compilation-next-file 1)
      (compile-goto-error)
```

should do what I want, but I get an error that the buffer is read-only, so clearly `compile-goto-error` is not changing the buffer when I call it programatically.

What do I need to do?

Comment: Check out `wgrep` when combined with the power of `multiple-cursors`.  Once you do, you will probably never look back.  When it is active, after doing a regular grep or recursive grep, I just hit:  `C-c C-p` (which is `wgrep-change-to-wgrep-mode`), and then I activate `multiple-cursors` by Magnar Sveen and make my edits all in one fell swoop, and then I exit that multiple-cursor mode and type `C-x C-s` (which is `wgrep-finish-edit`).

Comment: Pro tip when working with `wgrep` / `multiple-cursors`:  When dealing with an enormous amount of changes; e.g., 500 or more, `multiple-cursors` can get bogged down and become slow ... In such a case, `replace-string` when `wgrep` is active works well to change all occurrences.

Comment: What about using function `next-error`?